# CSS - Flex property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey guys I need to create a list of text which should align horizontally. The challenge is without giving width or margin the gap of each li should be same. And it should be responsive. ie, in some resolution if all the li can't stay horizontally it should automatically break and go down. Is that possible using flex ?

```css
ul {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: inherit;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> We identify unmet user </li>
  <li> We identify unmet </li>
  <li> We identify </li>
  <li> We identify unmet </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
You have to use `flex-direction: row` for horizontal and `flex-wrap: wrap` and it goes on 2-3 lines if needed.

If you want `flex-direction: column` - vertical - on smaller screens just use `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` - `max-width` or `min-width` depending on what you need.

Oh forgot .. for equal `spacing` you can use `justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex-wrap: wrap;` and li elements should have some width

Comment: Thanks Nemanja G, it's working. Now the li is center aligned. Can we start from left..?

Comment: @Coder95 you have padding from ul element, li elements will start from left to right. You can set up justify-content to different things, play around and get what you need

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `display: flex;` for that.

Remember to apply `flex-wrap: wrap` to parent and set `min-width` to children.

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/gZpNba